# Convert key, values to JSON

Tags: c++, qt, rapidjson

Recently I tried to create a JSON by qt and rapidjson like this:

```
{
      "version": "somestring",
      "testId": "somestring" ,
      "status": "somestring"
}
```

Bute always doing last addingMember, myCode:

```
QByteArray Serializer::Serilize(const std::vector<std::pair<QString, QString> > &values) {
    qDebug() << "values" << values;
    rapidjson::Document document;
    document.SetObject();
    auto &allocator{document.GetAllocator()};
    for (const auto &val : values) {
      qDebug() << val.first.toStdString().c_str()
               << val.second.toStdString().c_str();
      document.AddMember(rapidjson::StringRef(val.first.toStdString().c_str()),
                         rapidjson::StringRef(val.second.toStdString().c_str()),
                        allocator);
      qDebug() << document.HasMember(val.first.toStdString().c_str());
    } 
    return Serializer::Serilize(document);
}
```

All things passed right, but when I check (last line, HasMember...), Just has many (size of vector) key, values same as last value of vector.

Comment: I don't know `rapidjson`, but you're using a `c_str` pointing at a temporary std::string. If you are expecting that pointer to still be valid later, then that's a problem. Does `AddMember` make a copy of the string data, or does it just copy the pointer?

Comment: your right , but it's not problem, im really confused , this code on my laptop dont work but on another (same platform and  same ABI) it work perfectly!

Comment: When dealing with invalid pointers, sometimes they can still work, just by luck.

Comment: it's not undefined behavior , It's true ... I think that problem is another place of code ...